# Possible to pass a Map object to HQL

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is it possible to pass a whole map object to a HQL query without iterating over it? I would if I have to but thought there might be a cleaner way.

For example:

```
def aMap = ["foo":"bar", "bar":"foo"]

Foo.executeQuery("select p from p where p.bar in (:mapObj)", [mapObj: aMap])
```

Then have it automatically uses the key on the aMap?

If I try it it just throws this error:

> Remember that ordinal parameters are
>   1-based!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cryptic error says `executeQuery()` just expects a different Map as a last parameter - with a different data type or key names.

No, it won't automatically use Map's keys. If it ever did, I'd suppose that it should use `values()` instead. Anyway, it would be counter-intuitive.

So just use `aMap.keySet()`, it is about the absolute minimum of overhead you can get from `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for that, kind of understand it now. So I did this and it works perfectly and pretty fast. `Foo.executeQuery("select p from p where p.bar in (:mapObj)", [mapObj: aMap.keySet().toList()])` thus just passing a list of values to the IN operator.

Comment: You don't even need `toList()` - an unordered `Collection` will do.